# Split SQL 2017 column apart by Carriage Return and Line feed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with an Address column in SSMS 2017 that has Carriage Returns and Line Feeds.  One line in SQL is broken into three lines when pasting into Notepad.

Can someone help me break the single SQL column into multiple columns based on the Carriage Return and Line Feeds? I'm expecting to see the Address broken up into three different columns separated by CR and LF delimiter in SQL.

I've tried all the examples on the web that use `CHAR(13)` and `Char(10)` but they don't seem to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Paste from SQL into Notepad]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string_split` and `pivot` to get the desired result.

**Input text:**

[image: input from notepad++]

```
declare @t table (val nvarchar(1000))

insert into @t
select 'Smith, John
North Bend, 100 Bay Park, Field 2
Trever, NJ 11993
'
select * from @t

;WITH C AS
(
    SELECT value ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY val ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn
    FROM @t t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(val, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'~'), '~') AS SPL
)
SELECT [1] AS [Name]
      ,[2] AS Addr_1
      ,[3] AS Addr_2
FROM C
PIVOT
(
    MAX(VALUE)
    FOR RN IN([1],[2],[3])  
) as PVT
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table(
input nvarchar(255))
insert into @table 
values ('Smith, John 
North Bend, 100 Bay Park, Field 2
Trever, NJ 11993')

select 
pvt.[1] as [name] , 
pvt.[2] as [address], 
pvt.[3] as [city state & zip]
from 
(
     select * 
     from @table cross apply 
     (select rowN = row_number() over (order by (select null)), value from string_split(input, char(10)))d)src
pivot (
     max(value)
          for src.rowN in ([1], [2], [3])
) pvt
```

[link to fiddle uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fe4437be0b45aeef1172422d01967812)